# Replace lines containing special characters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, character

I want to replace all lines containing `TM_SPINDLE_OFF(3)` with `$(SPINDLE_OFF)(2)`
The file is an ASCII code file.

This is what I came up with without success:

```
powershell -command "(gc tr.cnc) -replace 'TM_SPINDLE_OFF(3)', '$(SPINDLE_OFF)(2)'
```

Comment: You need to backslash escape the () in the first part of the replace operation because they have special meaning in regex

Comment: "without success" - can you qualify your unsuccessfulness? Did it throw an error? Did the computer catch on fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
(gc d:\tr.cnc) -replace 'TM_SPINDLE_OFF\(3\)', '$(SPINDLE_OFF)(2)'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.